# best way to test form submitting

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I have a form that posts to an external url

```
<form method="post" action="http://api.domain.com/AddAnswer">
```

and I'm using MongoHQ to "dump" the result of that form

I wanted to make a simple test to submit 100 forms just to see if I get 100 answers in MongoHQ

Is there any available services out there for such, or I need to create my own auto-submitting?

**[Blitz.io](http://Blitz.io)** only work with GET's, and I was thinking as well that would be nice to test the browser as well, as Chrome always get the Origin error as form host and form action are in different servers (even though the form is submitted correctly).

If no service available for such scenario, how would you proceded?

I was thinking in creating a HTML page and hosted somewhere, then open a Windows/Web page that I would hit that url 100 times.

I could easily add

```
$(function() {

    var dt = new Date();

    // set date so we can have different posts data
    $("#dt").val(dt.getTime());

    // auto submit
    $("form").submit();
});
```

to the static page...

Comment: just add some kind of counter and run your `function` in a loop 100 times.

Comment: Use AJAX to do your form submitting and call that a hundred times.

Comment: You can also use fiddler to test your request http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: @alfasin true! dang, sometimes I just have the "complicator" turned on :/

Answer (score 0):

If I get your idea correct, you want to execute 100 post requests and then to verify that the response is correct.
If I am right, I can suggest you http://www.soapui.org/ . It is pretty simple to create that kind of test cases by following the tutorials they provide. Basically in your case you just need to develop a test which execute the request and verify the response content (if just waiting for response code 200 is not enough for you). Then you need to develop load test which call your verification test N-time. And that’s all. As a result you will have test case which verify that you have N right responses.